# Mysql aliased column unknown in the where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I do not understand why mysql says that there is unknown column in where clause. If I remove alias and just use log_archive.date then it works just fine.

Here is the sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(log_archive.msisdn) AS msisdn,
       DATE(log_archive.date) AS actionDate,
       users.activation_date

        FROM log_archive 

        INNER JOIN users on log_archive.msisdn = users.msisdn

        WHERE log_archive.action = 'pokrenuta aplikacija' AND
              actionDate BETWEEN ':start_date' AND ':end_date'

        ORDER BY actionDate DESC
```

Here is the error message:

> Unknown column 'actionDate' in 'where clause'

MySQL version is 5.1.36.

Comment: put it in having clause or replace it with date(log_archive.date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column alias name can't be used in `WHERE` clause.

## Reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.
>   This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
>   evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined. For
>   example, the following query is illegal:

Comment: I think this is not the right answer for this case, I'll explain it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because your actionDate is not a aliased name of column, actionDate is a aliase of the result of function `DATE`

If change the sql as below, it's still working, so problem is not the aliased name, you must use the exactly column in where clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(log_archive.msisdn) AS msisdn,
       log_archive.date AS actionDate,
       users.activation_date
FROM log_archive 
INNER JOIN users on log_archive.msisdn = users.msisdn
WHERE log_archive.action = 'pokrenuta aplikacija' AND
     DATE(actionDate) BETWEEN ':start_date' AND ':end_date'
ORDER BY actionDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Column aliases can't be used in the `WHERE` clause. You can move that logic into a derived table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT msisdn, actionDate, activation_date
FROM
(
  SELECT log_archive.msisdn AS msisdn,
         DATE(log_archive.date) AS actionDate,
         users.activation_date AS activation_date
  FROM log_archive 
      INNER JOIN users on log_archive.msisdn = users.msisdn
  WHERE log_archive.action = 'pokrenuta aplikacija'
) dt
WHERE actionDate BETWEEN ':start_date' AND ':end_date'
ORDER BY actionDate DESC
```

Or, MySQL users only, have the column alias condition in a `HAVING` clause.

Or simply put `DATE(log_archive.date) BETWEEN ...` in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Column alias name can't be used in WHERE clause. Instead Having clause can be used.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (log_archive.msisdn) AS msisdn,
    DATE(log_archive.date) AS actionDate,
    users.activation_date
FROM
    log_archive
        INNER JOIN
    users ON log_archive.msisdn = users.msisdn
WHERE
    log_archive.action = 'pokrenuta aplikacija'
having actionDate BETWEEN ':start_date' AND ':end_date'
ORDER BY actionDate DESC
```

You can also do it by

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (log_archive.msisdn) AS msisdn,
    DATE(log_archive.date) AS actionDate,
    users.activation_date
FROM
    log_archive
        INNER JOIN
    users ON log_archive.msisdn = users.msisdn
WHERE
    log_archive.action = 'pokrenuta aplikacija' AND DATE(log_archive.date) BETWEEN ':start_date' AND ':end_date'
ORDER BY actionDate DESC
```